# Where do the values for the graphical parameters in R come from?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Both base graphics in R and the ggplot2 package use the same encodings for different shapes and line types. See [here for the shapes](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/pchsymbols.php) and [here for the line types](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/line-types-in-r-lty).

These encoding systems seem very arbitrary to me, and thus I find them very difficult to remember or understand. In particular, since ggplot2 is all about an explicit philosophy of "grammar of graphics" it is somewhat surprising to me that it would continue the use of such arbitrary encoding systems from base R graphics.

**Question:** What is the reason or motivation for these encodings?
 Or if there is none, then what is the historical source for them? E.g. why should '2' be an empty triangle instead of a solid circle?

The R documentation for the [`points()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.4.0/topics/points) function indicates that some of the conventions are based on those used in the S language. But that only raises two questions (1) where did S get those conventions from, and (2) where did the remaining R conventions come from?

Answer (score 2):

From the S+ Documentation:

> pch="c" the character to be used for plotting points. If pch is a period, a centered plotting dot is used.
>
> pch=n the number of a plotting symbol to be drawn when plotting points. Basic marks are: square (0); octagon (1); triangle (2); cross (3); X (4); diamond (5) and inverted triangle (6). To get superimposed versions of the above use the following arithmetic(!): 7==0+4; 8==3+4; 9==3+5; 10==1+3; 11==2+6; 12==0+3; 13==1+4; 14==0+2. Filled marks are square (15), octagon (16), triangle (17), and diamond (18). Use the mkh graphics parameter to control the size of these marks. See the EXAMPLES section for a display of the plotting symbols. Using the numbers 32 through 126 for pch yields the 95 ASCII characters from space through tilde (see the SPLUS data set font). The numbers between 161 and 252 yield characters, accents, ligatures, or nothing, depending on the font (which is device dependent).

https://www.uni-muenster.de/ZIV.BennoSueselbeck/s-html/helpfiles/par.html